Raspberry Pi camera busy
I was trying to make my Raspberry Pi 4 stream a live recording.
I have this code (from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qs3KhLDUBmk):
import io 
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

def f():
    with Picamera2() as kamera:

        camera.resolution = (640, 480)
        camera.framerate = 18
        stream = io.BytesIO()

        for i in camera.capture_array(stream, "jpeg"):
            stream.seek(0)
            yield b"--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" + stream.read() + b"\r\n"
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()

@app.route("/v")
def videofeed():
    return Response(f(), mimetype="multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, threaded=True)

and it gives me this error:
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 257, in __init__
    self._open_camera()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 466, in _open_camera
    self.camera.acquire()
RuntimeError: Failed to acquire camera: Device or resource busy

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 335, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 324, in execute
    for data in application_iter:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 500, in __next__
    return self._next()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/response.py", line 50, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
  File "/home/usr/Desktop/main.py", line 8, in f
    with Picamera2() as camera:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 269, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("Camera __init__ sequence did not complete.")
RuntimeError: Camera __init__ sequence did not complete.


I think this means that the camera is being used by another application? How do I stop this?

first check if camera works with other programs.

maybe you should ask on similar portal for Raspberry or on official forum Raspberry Pi

BTW: there is program motion which works on Raspberry Pi - it can stream webcam as web page, and it can write screenshots (or video) at the same time (on Raspberry Pi card). It can also compare frames to detect motion.

If you started a stream previously and didn't Ctrl + C out of it, the camera will be occupied, and there's no easy way to stop it without a restart
